# В чем отличие условных выражений в Scala от Java?

Tags: java, scala

Прохожу курс на Coursera. Там объясняются условные выражения. Говорится, что они не похожи на условные выражения в `Java`. `Scala` в условных выражениях использует `expression` без `statements`. Но что мы видим на практике:

```
def abs(x: Double) = if (x < 0) -x else x
```

Не понимаю чем это будает отличаться от условного выражения в `Java`. Вроде все работает как в `Java`:

```
scala> def abs(x: Double) = if (x < 0) -x else x
abs: (x: Double)Double

scala> abs(-5)
res0: Double = 5.0

scala> abs(5)
res1: Double = 5.0
```

Comment: вы знаете разницу между **expression** и **statements**?

Answer (score 4):

Разница в том, что в **Scala** `if` - это вычисляемое выражение (его можно присвоить переменной), а в **Java** - это выполняемое выражение (его нельзя присвоить переменной).

**if**  в **Scala** похож на `?:` (тернарный оператор) из **Java**.